# How to give old Bounty without starting new one?

Tags: support, bounty

I started Bounty to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/308785/how-to-make-sure-that-only-one-wp-cron-runs-at-a-time), but I forget to give it. The accepted answer edit the question and solve my question totally. But I forget to give them.

Actually I thought it will apply for accepted answer automatically...

I want to give him to 50 rep which is on Bounty. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

That is weird, especially because there is only one answer to that question.
If I read the Help Center: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/bounty The bounty should have been awarded to this one question.

The thing is, did the answer had a minimum of 2 votes at the duration of the bounty? (This is crucial)

If it's indeed the case, you could try to contact a moderator by flagging the post and ask them to check if there's something going wrong.

> ### How is a bounty awarded?
>
> The bounty period lasts 7 days. Bounties must
>   have a minimum duration of at least 1 day. After the bounty ends,
>   there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty.
>   Simply click the bounty award icon next to each answer to permanently
>   award your bounty to the answerer. (You cannot award a bounty to your
>   own answer.)
>
> **If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),**
>   *the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a
>   minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full
>   amount, if the answer is also accepted).* If two or more eligible
>   answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer
>   is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is
>   awarded to anyone.
>
> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question
>   owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the
>   bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty
>   owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty
>   amount at the time of bounty expiration.
>
> As a special bonus, any reputation you earn from being awarded a
>   bounty is exempt from the daily reputation cap.